# Tests fail with tox because module under test can't be found

Tags: python, tox

I'm having some trouble with tox. Tests fail to run because the module under test can't be found. From the digging I've done, I suspect that the issue might be that tox is running tests with the wrong interpreter. I'm using Windows, if that's relevant.

Can't find package, even though it has been installed
into the venv:

```
C:\Users\galli\Desktop\projects\RedditBotBuilder>tox
GLOB sdist-make: C:\Users\galli\Desktop\projects\RedditBotBuilder\setup.py
py36 inst-nodeps: C:\Users\galli\Desktop\projects\RedditBotBuilder\.tox\dist\RedditBotBuilder-1.0.0.zip
py36 installed: attrs==17.4.0,certifi==2018.1.18,chardet==3.0.4,colorama==0.3.9,idna==2.6,more-itertools==4.1.0,pluggy==0.6.0,praw==5.4.0,prawcore==0.14.0,py==1.5.3,pytest==3.5.0,RedditBotBuilder==1.0.0,requests==2.18.4,six==1.11.0,update-checker==0.16,urllib3==1.22
py36 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='150'
py36 runtests: commands[0] | pytest --verbose tst/
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.5.0, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 -- c:\users\galli\desktop\projects\redditbotbuilder\.tox\py36\scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\galli\Desktop\projects\RedditBotBuilder, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________ ERROR collecting tst/redditbotbuilder/test_bots.py ______________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\galli\Desktop\projects\RedditBotBuilder\tst\redditbotbuilder\test_bots.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tst\redditbotbuilder\test_bots.py:3: in <module>
    from redditbotbuilder.bots import RedditBot
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redditbotbuilder.bots'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.22 seconds ===========================
ERROR: InvocationError: 'C:\\Users\\galli\\Desktop\\projects\\RedditBotBuilder\\.tox\\py36\\Scripts\\pytest.EXE --verbose tst/'
______________________________________________________ summary _______________________________________________________
ERROR:   py36: commands failed
```

Here's the directory structure, I've imported the project into PyCharm and it resolves the module without complaining:

```
src/
src/redditbotbuilder/
src/redditbotbuilder/bots.py
src/redditbotbuilder/__init__.py
tst/
tst/redditbotbuilder/
tst/redditbotbuilder/test_bots.py
tst/redditbotbuilder/__init__.py
tox.ini
setup.py
```

Here's `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    name="RedditBotBuilder",
    description="A Python framework for quickly building reddit bots",
    version="1.0.0",
    url="someUrl.com",
    author="Guy McGuyerson",
    author_email="guymcguyerson@gmail.com",
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules"
    ],
    packages=find_packages("src"),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    install_requires=["praw"]
)
```

Here's `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py36

[testenv]
deps=pytest
commands=pytest --verbose tst/
```

RedditBotBuilder has been installed in the venv:

```
(py36) C:\Users\galli\Desktop\projects\RedditBotBuilder\.tox\py36\Scripts>pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
attrs (17.4.0)
certifi (2018.1.18)
chardet (3.0.4)
colorama (0.3.9)
idna (2.6)
more-itertools (4.1.0)
pip (9.0.3)
pluggy (0.6.0)
praw (5.4.0)
prawcore (0.14.0)
py (1.5.3)
pytest (3.5.0)
RedditBotBuilder (1.0.0) <----------
requests (2.18.4)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.11.0)
update-checker (0.16)
urllib3 (1.22)
wheel (0.30.0)
```

I thought that maybe the wrong interpreter was being used...

```
(py36) C:\Users\galli\Desktop\projects\RedditBotBuilder\.tox\py36\Scripts>where python
C:\Users\galli\Desktop\projects\RedditBotBuilder\.tox\py36\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\galli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

...but after adding the statement `import sys; print(sys.executable)` to the test file, it printed `C:\Users\galli\Desktop\projects\RedditBotBuilder\.tox\py36\Scripts\python.exe`.

Comment: What does your `setup.py` file look like?

Comment: To import `redditbotbuilder.bots` there have to be `src/redditbotbuilder/__init__.py`. Is it there?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot to mention that `src/redditbotbuilder/__init__.py` and `tst/redditbotbuilder/__init__.py` both exist. I'll post `setup.py` when I have access to my home computer (might be a couple of hours), thanks for the help.

Comment: I have added `setup.py` to the post.

Comment: Also added some debug output, it seems that the correct interpreter is being used after all.

Comment: Well, this is just annoying. I can run the venv's python interpreter (`activate.bat; python`) and import the module from within it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I finally discovered the problem. The test module seems to be shadowing the name of the module under test. If I change the test module name to "notredditbotbuilder", everything works fine. I'm not sure why PyCharm didn't highlight this issue, but I don't want to spend any more time on it.